# Providing bounty to another user's question

Tags: discussion, support, questions, bounty

I want to give my bounty to a question(not mine) on Stack Overflow but I can't find the option to provide bounty.

I tried editing that question still I am unable to find the option to start a bounty.

How can I do that? Any guidance?

Comment: Is the question older than 2 days? If not, then you cannot yet offer a bounty.

Comment: yes guys question was asked toady only.

Comment: @NoDisplayName then you'll have to wait till the day after tomorrow to add a bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On other people's questions, you can find the "Start a Bounty" button underneath the "Add a Comment" button:

[image: Start a Bounty button]

As ProgramFOX mentioned [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281203/providing-bounty-to-another-users-question#comment134237_281203), this won't appear until the question is at least 2 days old.